# Alternate way to find all lexicographic orderings of a string in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, permutation, lexicographic

Problem: Find all the different ways to arrange a string
E.G. 123 can be arranged--123, 132, 213, 231, 321, 312

So I honestly have no idea how to go about engineering the solution to this problem, as I have not done any official Data Structures and Algorithms courses, but I came up with a more mathematical solution that I was able to turn into code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = 'ABCD'
    count = 0
    for first in string:
        if first is not string[0]:
            print()
        for second in string:
            if second is first:
                continue
            for third in string:
                if third in [second, first]:
                    continue
                for fourth in string:
                    if fourth in [third, second, first]:
                        continue
                    count += 1
                    print(str(first)+str(second)+str(third)+str(fourth), end=', ')
    print('\n{} possible combinations'.format(count))
```

but I have to manually add or remove for-loops depending on the size of the string. What methodology should I use to go about this problem

Comment: What is exact problem formulation? What is expected result?

Comment: @MBo I've edited in the problem to the post

Comment: `itertools.combinations`, it's in the standard library.

Comment: That's not what lexicographic means. (Princess Bride meme omitted.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to find all the permutations of the string. Python's standard library includes a [function for this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations('123'))
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '3', '2'), ('2', '1', '3'), ('2', '3', '1'), ('3', '1', '2'), ('3', '2', '1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

there is actually a very simple solution, only by using the ***itertools*** library;

```
from itertools import permutations
answer = [''.join(perm) for perm in permutations(s)]
```

That gives you a list of all the different permutations of s,
e.g.

```
s = 'abc'
```

Then the answer would be:

```
answer = ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```